# Undefined control sequence error when using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, undefined

I am getting the common "undefined control sequence" error and I have been searching its cause for hours now.

My Tex-Header reads like this :

```
 %_Allgemeine Einstellungen__________________________________________________________________________

% Dokumentenformat
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

% Umlaute unter UTF8 nutzen
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Packet für Seitenrandabständex und Einstellung für Seitenränder
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left=3.5cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm}
    \reversemarginpar

% Zeichenencoding
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Deutsche Sonderzeichen benutzen 
    \usepackage{ngerman}

% deutsche Silbentrennung
    \usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

% Mathematische Symbole importieren
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,nicefrac,mathrsfs}
% Kapitelnummer in Gleichungsnummer
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}


% auf SI-Einheiten zurückgreifen
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
            exponent-product=\cdot,
            }

% auf jeder Seite eine Überschrift (alt, zentriert)
    %\pagestyle{headings}

% bei englischen Dokumenten 1st,2nd,3rd, usw
    %\usepackage[super]{nth}

% Schaltet den zusätzlichen Zwischenraum ab, den LaTeX normalerweise nach einem Satzzeichen einfügt.
    \frenchspacing

% Paket für Zeilenabstand
    \usepackage{setspace}

% Formatierung der Absätze
    \setlength{\parindent}{1em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}

% Keine einzelnen Linie am Start des Paragraphen (Schusterjungen)
    \clubpenalty = 10000
% Keine einzelnen Linie am Ende des Paragraphen (Hurenkinder)
    \widowpenalty = 10000
    \displaywidowpenalty = 10000

% Symbole wie ° in Texten
    \usepackage{textcomp}


%_Inhalt, Verzeichnisse & Zitate____________________________________________________________________

% Neue Namen für Verzeichnisse, Abbildungen und Tabellen
    \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
    %\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}
    %\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listtablename}{Tabellen}
    \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
    \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}

    \setkomafont{caption}{\small}
    \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% erzeugt Inhaltsverzeichnis mit Querverweisen zu den Kapiteln (PDF Version)
    \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref} 
    \hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue!50!black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black}
    %\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, linkcolor= black, urlcolor=black}

% für Stichwortverzeichnis
    \usepackage{makeidx}

% Festlegung Art der Zitierung - Havardmethode: Abkuerzung Autor + Jahr
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{/Masterarbeit/Script/Quellen/neu/literatur}

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
    \usepackage[withpage]{acronym}

% ToDo Notizen
    \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,         % frabiges Rechteck in Todo Liste
                prependcaption,             
                %color=green,               % Farbe im Code
                bordercolor=black!50,
                linecolor=orange!50,            
                backgroundcolor=orange!50,
                %figwidth=length,
                %textwidth=length,
                textsize=tiny
                ]{todonotes}
    %\PassOptionsToPackage{disable}{todonotes}      Deaktiviert alle TodoNotes!
                                                %   kann auch später im Hauptdokument 
                                                %   verwendet werden!
% Notizen beginnen am Rand des Dokuments        
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}


%_Kopf- & Fußzeilen_________________________________________________________________________________
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Leere Fußzeile
    \fancyfoot{}
%Linke Seite der Kopfzeile
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

%_Eigene Formatierungen_____________________________________________________________________________
    \newcommand{\codepar}[1]{\textcolor{blue!50!black}{\ttfamily#1} }
    \newcommand{\codeequ}[2]{\textcolor{blue!50!black}{\ttfamily#1} = #2  }
    \newcommand{\namelist}[1]{\textcolor{red!50!black}{\ttfamily#1} }

    \newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

    \newcommand{\qm}{$\text{m}^2$}
    \newcommand{\pow}[1]{$\text{#1}^2$}
    \newcommand{\powt}[1]{$\text{#1}^3$}
    \newcommand{\pown}[2]{$\text{#1}^#2$}

%_Grafiken_____________________________________________________________________________

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usepackage{floatflt}
    \usepackage{caption}
    %\newcommand{\dontcountfig}{\addtocounter{figure}{-1}}

%_Farben_____________________________________________________________________________
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{UniBlue}{RGB}{83,121,170}

%_Tabellen_____________________________________________________________________________
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}

% mehrseitige Tabellen ermöglichen
    \usepackage{longtable}
% Tabellen wie in Büchern
    \usepackage{booktabs}
% Toprule usw.
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newlength{\toprulewidth}
        \setlength{\toprulewidth}{0.2ex}
        \patchcmd{\toprule}{\heavyrulewidth}{\toprulewidth}{}{}
    \newlength{\bottomrulewidth}
        \setlength{\bottomrulewidth}{0.30ex}
        \patchcmd{\bottomrule}{\heavyrulewidth}{\bottomrulewidth}{}{}

%_Code_____________________________________________________________________________
    \input{/home/jens/Dokumente/LaTeX/listings.tex}

%_TIKZ_____________________________________________________________________________
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees,positioning,intersections,backgrounds,decorations.markings,matrix}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \tikzset{
        invisible/.style={opacity=0},
        visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
        alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
            \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}},}
```

My Error log says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ->\iffieldundef 
                           {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield ...
l.17 \begin{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ...f {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring 
                                              {from\thefield {origlangua...
l.17 \begin{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ...} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield 
                                              {origlanguage}}\space }
l.17 \begin{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@sfromlang ->\iffieldundef 
                           {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield ...
l.17 \begin{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@sfromlang ...f {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring 
                                              {from\thefield {origlangua...
l.17 \begin{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@sfromlang ...} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield 
                                              {origlanguage}}\space }
l.17 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I also get the error when my literatur.bib file is only filled with one example entry and I comment out all my text and compile a blank sheet with only a cite to my example entry. So the error has to be inside  the header.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could tell me my mistake ! :)

Thank you guys

PS: Sorry for the german comments in the Header :D

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please show us the complete error message? If your editor does not show it, open the .log file and  search for `Undefined control sequence`. The lines following this error should tell which control sequence is undefined.

Comment: You should not need `\usepackage{ngerman}` as you are loading babel.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell us *which* command is supposed to be undefined? Unfortunately, the code you posted does not really help us to identify the problem, we can't run it. Please consider providing a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that we can actually run.

Comment: With only a few exceptions, `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: You need to specify the file extension in `\addbibresource`, so you probably need `\addbibresource{/Masterarbeit/Script/Quellen/neu/literatur.bib}` (this is very likely not the cause of your undefined control sequence, but should be taken car of nonetheless). `citestyle=authoryear` alone looks a bit meh with a numeric bibliography, try `\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}` instead.

Comment: Mhhh, try  `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead of `\usepackage{ngerman}`.

Comment: Please find out what version of `biblatex` you are using. This can be done by adding `\listfiles` to the beginning of your document. If you get errors, just compile on and show us the list with the package versions you get at the end.

Comment: Thank you alot ! removing the     `\usepackage{ngerman}`     fixed my issue :)

Comment: @samcarter Sounds like you got it. Want to write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The package `ngerman` is outdated and should be replaced with the `babel` package (see http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?52211-Tip-Veraltete-Pakete-welche-NICHT-verwendet-werden-sollten for a list with more outdated packages). As your code already contains `babel` you can simply remove `\usepackage{ngerman}`.

---

Some other thoughts about your preamble:

- With only a few exceptions, the package `hyperref` should be loaded after the other packages, see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) for more information.
- as moewe mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398624/undefined-control-sequence-error-when-using-biblatex#comment991707_398624),  `.bib` is misisng from `\addbibresource{/Masterarbeit/Script/Quellen/neu/literatur}`
- I am not sure if

  ```
  \tikzset{
      invisible/.style={opacity=0},
      visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
      alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
          \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}},}
  ```

  makes sense in a non-beamer document.
- `\frenchspacing` is probably unnecessary, as `babel` automatically set this based on the language which is en effect.